# Two if statements. Both work. Only one prints

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm trying to rotate a fixed image in sync with `fullpage.js` and it works for the most part.

In order to prevent unwanted rotation I have to stack css `rotate()` values.

It works when I scroll down and it stacks as I wanted (ie. 180, 360, 540, ..)

It doesn't work when I scroll up.

I tried to use alerts to identify if the calculation is done, there seems to be no problem on the stacking, but scroll up portion of the code simply doesn't print to the HTML document.

Here's my code;

```
var rotation = 0,
    rotationInc = 180,
    miniLogo = $('#mini-logo');

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#home').fullpage({
    verticalCentered: false,
    scrollingSpeed: 300,
    onLeave: function (index, nextIndex, direction) {
      if (direction == 'down') {
        rotation += rotationInc;

        setTimeout(function () {
          miniLogo.addClass('enlarge');
        }, 400);

        miniLogo.each(function () {
          alert(rotation);
        });

        setTimeout(function () {
          miniLogo.css({
            'transform': 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)'
          });
        }, 800);

        setTimeout(function () {
          miniLogo.removeClass('enlarge');
        }, 1200);
      }

      if (direction == 'up') {
        rotation -= rotationInc;

        setTimeout(function () {
          miniLogo.addClass('enlarge');
        }, 400);

        miniLogo.each(function () {
          alert(rotation);
        });

        setTimeout(function () {
          miniLogo.css({
            'transform': 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg);'
          });
        }, 800);

        setTimeout(function () {
          miniLogo.removeClass('enlarge');
        }, 1200);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The first if statement works perfectly. The second gives the alert I wanted but doesn't print the reduced degree on the html.

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm sure I've done a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
rotation = 0;
rotationInc = 180;
miniLogo = $('#mini-logo');

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#home').fullpage({
    verticalCentered: false,
    scrollingSpeed: 300,
    onLeave: function (index, nextIndex, direction) {

    var rotation = (direction == 'down') 
        ? rotation += rotationInc
        : rotation -= rotationInc;

        setTimeout(function () {
          miniLogo.addClass('enlarge');
        }, 400);

        miniLogo.each(function () {
          alert(rotation);
        });

        setTimeout(function () {
          miniLogo.css({
            'transform': 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)'
          });
        }, 800);

        setTimeout(function () {
          miniLogo.removeClass('enlarge');
        }, 1200);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain where the error is? Was it just the angle rotation or anything else?

Comment: @Kevorkian This was what I tried first. The degree of the rotation needs to be stacked up and down in order to achieve rotation animation every time a direction passed from `fullpage.js` because there are many slides/sections. Your code only animates once when scrolled down and then stops animating, also it drops from `180deg` to `-180deg` causing it to animate a whole  `360deg` when scrolling up.

Comment: @shiri The error is when scrolling up it does not update the inline css, which results in no animation. Other than that it behaves as I wanted, I'm guessing having `miniLogo.css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)' }); ` on both if statements messes it up somehow.

Comment: excactly , the problem is not updating the css when scrolling up,@MeteCirakoglu there is a missing ";" at the end of 'transform': 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)'

Comment: @Kovarkian Thanks! Although it was not the missing `;` but rather it was the addition of `;` at the end of second `miniLogo.css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)' });`.

Comment: well it is the exact same thing, I've accepted your answer as it lead to this conversation.